Parallelism in the SVM vs Fees
When transactions are processed, does the proposer get credited iteratively after every transaction in commit_transaction? when the Fee is actually applied to the fee payer / signer?
If so does that mean that the fee payer must grab a writelock to the fee receiver writable account - and every single transaction must do this (to debit the proposer)
How do you get parallelism in this case?

To put it simply, you've understood everything correctly -- you can't reliably parallelize transactions that all use the same fee payer, since the fee payer must have the fee deducted from their account. Fees are deducted when each batch of transactions is committed, and batches currently do not have conflicting transactions.

i meant more to say to the fee receiver! ie) what happens in the case of (1. block proposer spends their tx fees in mid block)
